# Passing a C structure to a function in C DLL

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I've a `.DLL` which creates "named" a shared memory using some utility functions inside it

I need to write/read following C `struct` via python using functions having following prototype:

- `int write_shmem(const char* shmem_name, char* shmem)`
- `int read_shmem ( const char* shmem_name , char* shmem);`

in the `.DLL` file

- `shmem_name` is shared memory name
- `shmem` is the data to be written

The C `struct` is similar to

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char c;
   unsigned long l;
   float f;
   double d;
 } DataBlock ;
```

I'm using following in python code

```
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('shared_mem.dll')
write_shmem = dll.write_shmem
write_shmem.restype = ctypes.c_int

read_shmem = dll.read_shmem
read_shmem.restype = ctypes.c_int

class DataBlock(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('c', c_ubyte), ('l', c_ulong),
                ('f',c_float), ('d', c_double) ]

data = DataBlock('A',123, 12.32, 1.89721)

write_shmem(c_char_p(b'P0W') , ??? ) #  cast(data, POINTER(c_char) ?

#...

read_shmem(c_char_p(b'P0W'),  ??? )  #  cast(data, POINTER(c_char) ?
```

How to typecast to `char*` ?

Will using casting correctly puts the data to shared memory ? I need to read the same shared memory from a C application

**Edit**

Using:

`int create_shmem(const char*, long long );` from `.DLL` I'm creating a "named" shared memory

Python code :

```
create_shmem( c_char_p(b'P0W'),
               ctypes.c_longlong(sizeof(DataBlock)) )
```

`write_shmem` and  `read_shmem` will simply write/read data by using the size of created memory. This is done in `.DLL` functions itself. (`Boost` Interprocess Shared Memory Object is used here)

<sup>***Using Python Version : 3.3.0***</sup>

Comment: How does `write_shmem` know the size of data to write? Similarly, how does `read_shmem` know how much data to read? Are you implicitly using `sizeof(DataBlock)` in their implementation?

Comment: @crayzeewulf yes, using `int create_shmem(const char*, long long );` from the dll I'm creating shared memory of known size

Comment: Try: `write_shmem("blah", byref(data))`. Same for `read_shmem`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not have your versions of `read_shmem` and `write_shmem` functions. So I created the following dummy versions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned long l;
    float f;
    double d;
} DataBlock ;

int write_shmem(const char* shmem_name, char* data)
{
    DataBlock* block = (DataBlock*)data ;
    printf("%c %ld %f %lf\n", block->c, block->l, block->f, block->d) ;
    return sizeof(DataBlock) ;
}

int read_shmem(const char* shmem_name, char* data) 
{
    DataBlock* block = (DataBlock*)data ;
    block->c = 'z' ;
    block->l = 3 ;
    block->f = block->d = 3.14 ;
    return sizeof(DataBlock) ;
}
```

In the Python code, I can call them this way:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libshmem.so')

write_shmem = dll.write_shmem
write_shmem.restype = c_int

read_shmem = dll.read_shmem
read_shmem.restype = c_int

class DataBlock(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('c', c_ubyte), ('l', c_ulong),
                ('f',c_float), ('d', c_double) ]

#
# Using byref()
#
data = DataBlock(ord('A'), 123, 12.32, 1.89721)

write_shmem(b"P0W", byref(data))
read_shmem(b"P0W", byref(data))

print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(chr(data.c), data.l, data.f, data.d))

#
# Using pointer()
#
data = DataBlock(ord('A'), 123, 12.32, 1.89721)

write_shmem(b"P0W", pointer(data))
read_shmem(b"P0W", pointer(data))

print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(chr(data.c), data.l, data.f, data.d))

#
# Using cast()
#
data = DataBlock(ord('A'), 123, 12.32, 1.89721)

write_shmem(b"P0W", cast(pointer(data), c_char_p))
read_shmem(b"P0W", cast(pointer(data), c_char_p))

print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(chr(data.c), data.l, data.f, data.d))
```

The output in each case ([`byref`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref), [`pointer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer), or [`cast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) usage) is:

```
A 123 12.320000 1.897210
z 3 3.140000104904175 3.14
```

I am using Linux so I am creating a shared object library from the C code using the following `Makefile`:

```
libshmem.so: dummy_shmem.o
    gcc -shared -o libshmem.so dummy_shmem.o

dummy_shmem.o: dummy_shmem.c
    gcc -fpic -c dummy_shmem.c
```

But the behavior should be about the same on Windows.

## Unsolicited Suggestion

Note that using `write_shmem` and `read_shmem` with implicit knowledge of the size of the data buffer passed to them is dangerous. You will get strange results if you accidentally pass another type of object to them. A safer option might be to create shims around these functions to explicitly manage `DataBlock` instances. Here is an example where I have dummy implementations of `create_shmem`, `write_shmem`, and `read_shmem`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned long l;
    float f;
    double d;
} DataBlock ;

static char* dummy_shmem = 0 ;
static size_t shmem_size = 0 ;

int create_shmem(const char* shmem_name, const size_t data_size)
{
    free(dummy_shmem) ;
    dummy_shmem = 0 ;
    shmem_size = 0 ;

    dummy_shmem = malloc(data_size) ;
    shmem_size = dummy_shmem ? data_size : 0 ;

    return shmem_size ;
}

int write_shmem(const char* shmem_name, const char* data, const size_t data_size)
{
    if (data_size <= shmem_size) {
        memcpy(dummy_shmem, data, data_size) ;
        return data_size ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

int read_shmem(const char* shmem_name, char* data, const size_t data_size) 
{
    if (data_size <= shmem_size) {
        memcpy(data, dummy_shmem, data_size) ;
        return data_size ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

int create_block(const char* shmem_name)
{
    printf("create_block: %s\n", shmem_name) ;
    return create_shmem(shmem_name, sizeof(DataBlock)) ;
}

int write_block(const char* shmem_name, const DataBlock* data)
{
    printf("write_block: [%s] %c %ld %f %lf\n", shmem_name, data->c, data->l, data->f, data->d) ;
    return write_shmem(shmem_name, (char*)data, sizeof(DataBlock)) ;
}

DataBlock read_block(const char* shmem_name)
{
    DataBlock result ;
    read_shmem(shmem_name, (char*)&result, sizeof(DataBlock)) ;
    printf("read_block: [%s] %c %ld %f %lf\n", shmem_name, result.c, result.l, result.f, result.d) ;
    return result ;
}
```

Then the Python code becomes a lot simpler, cleaner, and safer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libshmem.so')

class DataBlock(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('c', c_ubyte), ('l', c_ulong),
                ('f',c_float), ('d', c_double) ]

create_block = dll.create_block
create_block.argtypes = [c_char_p]
create_block.restype = c_int

write_block = dll.write_block
write_block.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(DataBlock)]
write_block.restype = c_int

read_block = dll.read_block
read_block.argtypes = [c_char_p]
read_block.restype = DataBlock
#
# Create memory block 
#
create_block(b"P0W")    
#
# Write data block to shmem
#
in_data = DataBlock(ord('A'), 123, 12.32, 1.89721)
write_block(b"P0W", in_data)
#
# Read data block from shmem. 
#
out_data = read_block(b"P0W")

print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(chr(in_data.c), in_data.l, in_data.f, in_data.d))
print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(chr(out_data.c), out_data.l, out_data.f, out_data.d))
```

Updates:

- Passing `DataBlock` by reference to `write_block` (see eryksun's comments below).

Comment: Thanks, what difference will it make with [`cast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) ?

Comment: Update: You can use `cast` and `pointer` too. But using `cast` results in less readable code. Using `pointer` is slower than using `byref` according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer). I have updated the above sample code with some examples.

Comment: @P0W, I had left out the 'b' in front of the shmem names in the code. I have corrected it so that the name gets passed as a byte literal.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks and good points. There is a lot of room for improvement here (both in style and efficiency). I wanted to have a gradual transition from P0W's original code to a more complex code. I was even tempted to do the whole thing in C++ but thought that would be too different from P0W's original code. In any case, your points are all valid. I have updated the second code to pass `const DataBlock*` to `write_block`.

Comment: The same applies to `read_block`. For a C caller the compiler reserves space on the stack and calls `read_block` with an implicit pointer. When `read_block` returns, the `result` is copied from the local variable to the implicit address. I need to check this, but I think with ctypes there may be yet another copy from the buffer set up by libffi. anyway, it's more efficient to have the caller allocate the `DataBlock` as an out parameter passed by reference.